# Configuring pip3 - How to reverse action of `pypy3 -m ensurepip` and get back pip3 for classical python3?

Tags: python, pip, pypy, ensurepip

I wanted to install a package to be used with pypy3. I blindly followed some instructions (which I don't remember now, it was decent time ago), most likely using `pypy3 -m ensurepip` script to setup pip for pypy3.

Okey, now running `pip3 install xyz` installs xyz for pypy3 (and not python3). But I want to be back and use pip3 (or any other command) for the normal cpython python3.

Running `pip3 --version` yields pip `21.1.2 from /home/zaabson/.local/lib/pypy3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)`. And `which pip3 == /home/zaabson/.local/bin/pip3` so I belive it's still the same pip3 just configured for pypy3 and I don't know what to change to fully reconfigure it.

Best would be to be able to switch between installing for python3 and pypy3, but I want to stick to global installations as always and not bother with virtualenv's. Also I'm on **ubuntu** so removing python is out of question, as the whole system depends on it.

Also wishfully running `python3 -m ensurepip(3)` gets `/usr/bin/python3 No module named ensurepip` and how can I get it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just run `pypy3 -m pip install` and `python3-m pip install` depending on what you want. the executable `pip3` is ambiguous here.

Comment: Unsure why it ended up in `/home/zaabson/.local/bin/pip3`, but you can simply remove this file (or the whole directory after checking it contains nothing of interest to you).

Comment: Thanks, `(python3/pypy3) -m pip install xyz` is the way.

Comment: @ArminRigo I now inspected this "/.local/bin/pip3" and its a python script so starting with `#!/usr/bin/pypy3`. Just for fun I've changed it to `#!/usr/bin/python3` and now indeed command "pip3" installs for python3 as I wanted :D